# Spread values over a year in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, modulo

I need to forecast project values along the year.

I have for example:

```
3 'A' Projects per year
5 'B' Projects per year
20 'C' Projects per year
```

Projects all worth 10$.

Setup range:

[image: Spread values over year screenshot]

I need to spread their values in a months table, in google sheet (or excel) using formulas.

Expected result : 
[image: expected result screenshot]

I thought it was a very similar issue than "one every N-th column", so I tried using modulo:

In E2:

```
=$C2*ROUND(DIVIDE($B2,12))+IF(MOD(MONTH(E$1),12/$B2)=0,$C2,0)
```

But it works only when 'nb per year' is a divider of 12 (1,2,3,4,6..)

I don't need any particular spread rule (random, counting from the first month ..) as soon as I have N projects total in the whole year.

**How can I do?**

Thanks a lot for the help !

- Arno

Comment: I don't see any logic to the `Expected Result:` image. It's hard to do that without some sort of logic. Why don't you just take the total value `projects per year * value`, divide it by 12 and plug that amount in each month's cell?

Comment: As I said : no particular logic expected, any will do.
I don't want values to be averaged, I need to keep discrete values in table. (it's for a forecast plan with a lot of one-shot deals, so with high cash flow variations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
=$C2*(INT(COLUMN(B:B)/(12/$B2))-INT(COLUMN(A:A)/(12/$B2)))
```

[image]

My spacing is slightly different than yours, but it is close.

Comment: Wow ! I can't believe it works .. It makes very my humble about my excel skills, I spent 3 hours struggling on this one ...
Still trying to understand how this mathemagical trick works, still ! Thank you very much @Scott, you're a life saver